# Sentry: Enable readable stack traces when using React

Tags: reactjs, netlify, sentry

I am using Sentry to catch any error on production with Netlify's plugin to upload the `source maps`.

I got the message:

[image]

> Error matching your configuration.Configure Stack Trace Linking to fix this problem.

What I should fill on "Stack Trace Root" and in "Source Code Root"?

[image]

Comment: Can you add more details on how you are integrating sentry with your app and which netlify pluign did you use and its config?